# authentication drops off after ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If my authentification in rails made with devise drops off after i make destructive or constructive (`delete/insert`) request, what am i doing wrong? Is it about authenticity token? How should i apply it to my request?

I'm using `rails 3.0.9` and `rails.jquery.js`

my link is like that:

<%= link_to "delete", photo_path(p), :class => "instant-link destroy-link", :method => 'delete', :confirm => "sure?", :remote => true %>

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer!

The problem is about including this code after `<%= csrf_meta_tag %>`:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
  var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);
});
```

It includes csrf token in every ajax request, so it becomes ‘legal’